# EmberJS : JSON-API Errors for one field are included in other field's errors

Tags: ember.js, json-api

I have a ticket model with only a subject and content field.

```
subject: DS.attr('string'),
content: DS.attr('string')
```

On a new wiew, submitting a new ticket with content but without a subject return the following error :

```
{"errors":[{"source":{"pointer":"/data/attributes/subject"},"detail":"doit être rempli(e)"}]}`
```

Here is the controller action :

```
saveTicket(ticket){
      let promise=ticket.save();
      promise.then(
        () => this.transitionToRoute('tickets')
      );
      return promise;
    }
```

`ticket.errors.subject[0].message` correctly contain the detail from the server's answer, however, `ticket.errors.content[0].message` also contain the error message.

Why is the error attached to every field ?

Comment: What ember-data version are you using? Are you able to reproduce in an Ember Twiddle? Note that you could use Mirage in Ember Twiddle to mock your api. Sounds like a bug IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`content` is a reserved word. As soon as I changed the attribute name it worked.

Comment: Good investigation! There is also an open PR to add an assertion for that one: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/5755